# Delete last two character of a string - Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: string, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

This is probably a stupid question but I can't figure out for the life of me which step would allow the last two character of a string to be deleted in Pentaho Data Integration V9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, perhaps the simplest is a Replace in strings step, using a Regex (e.g., search for `(.*).{2}` and replace by `$1`).

This will replace the entire string by the first capture group, which is made up of the entire string except the last two characters.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. It was a solution indeed, i'm not very familiar with regex, but i will try to learn it. If there is any site with material about it i would be glad to know it. Many thanks my friend!

Comment: Try this: https://www.regular-expressions.info/